# Mobile UI for time duration

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I'm using a datetimepicker to enter a duration of time in a form. The UI works well on a computer, but works poorly in a mobile environment. I haven't been able to find a good alternative that works well across all platforms to record duration.

Heres an example of the datetimepicker

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"> <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>

$(function(){
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
format: 'hh:mm:ss'
});

 });
```

And the fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/jagtx65n/

Is it possible to force a different UI in mobile that will still work effectively, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following datetime picker in my cordova project.

[Responsive jQuery DateTime Picker library for Web & Mobile](https://github.com/CuriousSolutions/DateTimePicker)

It looks very good in my mobile view.A sample html code using this plugin is given below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/DateTimePicker.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/DateTimePicker.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function ()
            {
                $("#dtBox").DateTimePicker({
                    "timeFormat": "hh:mm:ss AA"
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><p>Time : </p>
            <input type="text" data-field="time" readonly>
            <div id="dtBox"></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Kiran Muralee that looks nice, but I'm actually using this to enter a duration of time rather than a time of date. I also need it to be in hh:mm:ss (seconds are important in this instance).

Comment: What you need is really possible with the plugin.Just use  "timeFormat": "hh:mm:ss AA".Refer this link for more details http://curioussolutions.github.io/DateTimePicker/.I have edited my answer to include a sample html code using the plugin.